# Cannot track "Reviewer" badge

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress, review-badges

I have more than 500 reputation on Stack Overflow and have reviewed twenty–thirty posts in the [*First questions* review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review). Now I suppose I have the right to get the "Reviewer" badge.

I want to track it, but when I try to select my next badge, it doesn't exist in the badges list, though "Custodian" (already earned) exists when I select the "All" tab. "Reviewer" doesn't exist in any tab.

Is this a bug, or is the "Reviewer" badge still inaccessible for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.

You can track your Reviewer badges through the Review Queues, on the Stats tab (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)):

[image]

I assume it's untrackable (untraceable?) through your profile since there is a Reviewer badge for every review queue, and they would need to be distinguishable.